# Can only edit last row of Dojo DataGrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I am using a dojo datagrid that is displaying data either coordinate data sent from a server, or coordinate data from pins which are added to an ESRI map.

However, when I click on a cell to edit the text box displays and you can change the value yet the change does not save unless you are editing the final row. If you edit a text box in row 2 and then click the box in the same column for the final row, the row 2 value is put in the final row.

If you exit any other way row 2 data reverts back to its original value. The final row behaves exactly how I want it to, you can edit all the values and they are saved (unless page is refreshed). If another row is added, and you try to edit it the row will throw a

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined " error on ObjectStore.js:8.

I started with the code from the hellodgrid example 
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/working_grid/demo/ using the "Editing data with the Grid" and edited columns in any row.

I haven't seen a problem that's anything like mine and I am really stumped, so any help is appreciated.

Data in the following code is an array of objects I created.

```
    function drawTable(data){
        require([
            "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
            "dojox/grid/cells",
            "dojox/grid/cells/dijit",
            "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
            "dojo/date/locale",
            "dojo/currency",
            "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
            "dojox/grid/_CheckBoxSelector",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], function(DataGrid, cells, cellsDijit, Memory, ObjectStore, locale, currency,
            DateTextBox, _CheckBoxSelector){
            function formatDate(inDatum){
                return locale.format(new Date(inDatum), this.constraint);
            }
            gridLayout = [
              {
      type: "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector",
      defaultCell: { width: 8, editable: true, type: cells._Widget, styles: 'text-align: right;' }
              }, 
              //cells:
                    [

        { name: 'Number', field: 'order', editable: false /* Can't edit ID's of dojo/data items */ },
                    { name: 'ID', field: 'uniqueID', width: 10, editable: false /* Can't edit ID's of dojo/data items */ },
                    { name: 'Station ID', field: 'stationID', width: 15, editable: true },
                    /* No description for each station... at least not yet
        { name: 'Description', styles: 'text-align: center;', field: 'description', width: 10,
                        type: cells.ComboBox, 
                        options: ["normal","note","important"]},*/
                  { name: 'Road', field: 'road', width: 10, editable: true, styles: 'text-align: center;',
                        type: cells.CheckBox},  
                    { name: 'Route', field: 'route', width: 10, editable: true, styles: 'text-align: center;',
                        type: cells.CheckBox},
                    { name: 'Count Type', width: 13, editable: true, field: 'countType',
                        styles: 'text-align: center;',
                        type: cells.Select,
                        options: ["new", "read", "replied"] },
                    { name: 'Count Duration', field: 'countDuration', styles: '', width: 15, editable: true},
                    /*  
                  May want to use this later                    
                { name: 'Date', field: 'col8', width: 10, editable: true,
                        widgetClass: DateTextBox,
                        formatter: formatDate,
                        constraint: {formatLength: 'long', selector: "date"}}, */

                ]
              //{
            ];


            objectStore = new Memory({data:data});

            stationGridStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: objectStore});

            //  create the grid.
            grid = new DataGrid({
                store: stationGridStore,
            structure: gridLayout,
    //          rowSelector: '20px',
                "class": "grid"
            }, "grid");
            grid.startup();

//          grid.canSort=function(){return false;};
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included your actual data in the question, but based on one of your columns, I am guessing your data items store a unique identifier in a property called `uniqueID`.  However, `dojo/store/Memory` by default assumes that unique IDs are in the `id` property.  That mismatch may very well be what's causing your issue.

You can inform `dojo/store/Memory` that your unique identifiers are under another property by setting `idProperty` on the instance:

```
objectStore = new Memory({ data: data, idProperty: 'uniqueID' });
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I had no idea that it assumed the id property. If only every fix was that easy...